# Pandas: how to create a simple counter that increases each n rows?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to create a Counter that increases by one each n rows?

example ===> Counter increasing each 4 rows:

```
        counter
    0    1
    1    1
    2    1
    3    1
    4    2
    5    2
    6    2
    7    2
    8    3
    9    3
```

I was trying `df['counter'] = np.arange(len(df)//4)` but I get lenght of index error

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, need:

```
df['counter'] = np.arange(len(df)) // 4 + 1
print (df)
   counter
0        1
1        1
2        1
3        1
4        2
5        2
6        2
7        2
8        3
9        3
```

Your solution not working, because array with 2 values was assigned to column:

```
print (len(df)//4)
2

print (np.arange(len(df)//4))
[0 1]
```

But if need array with same size like `DataFrame`:

```
print (np.arange(len(df)))
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```