# Adding new column to pandas dataframe with same element multiple times

Tags: arrays, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'SENDER_ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] })

df =
   SENDER_ID
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
6   7
7   8
8   9
9   10
10  11
11  12
```

Now I want to add a column which has the the element multiple times.

```py
    SENDER_ID   counter
0   1           0
1   2           0
2   3           0
3   4           1
4   5           1
5   6           1
6   7           2
7   8           2
8   9           2
9   10          3
10  11          3
11  12          3
```

The dataframe always has a length of multiple of 3 and is much larger then in this simple example.

What is the easiest and most generic way to add this new column?

Comment: Floor division ->`df['counter'] = df.index // 3` (assuming default RangeIndex as shown) or `df['counter'] = np.arange(len(df)) // 3` if DataFrame has MultiIndex. [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53540509/15497888)

Answer (score 1):

Another way using [`pd.RangeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.RangeIndex.html):

```
df['count'] = pd.RangeIndex(0, len(df)//3).repeat(3)
print(df)

# Output:
    SENDER_ID  count
0           1      0
1           2      0
2           3      0
3           4      1
4           5      1
5           6      1
6           7      2
7           8      2
8           9      2
9          10      3
10         11      3
11         12      3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution which works:

```py
max_list_length = int(len(df) / 3)

liste = [[n]*3 for n in range(0,max_list_length)]
value = sum(liste, [])

>>>> value
>>>> [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]


for n in range (0, len(df)):
    df.at[n, 'counter'] = value[n]
```

Comment: Replace `int(len(df) / 3)` by true div: `len(df) // 3` and your loop by `df['counter'] = value`